# Duplicate relationship in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Why does this create two relationships instead of one?

```
MATCH (a:Person{name:'Barack'}), (b:Person{name:'Raback'})
CREATE (a)-[r:SHAKES_HANDS_WITH{id:toString(rand())}]->(b)
RETURN r
```

*(Random number "id" is just added for demo purposes.)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have 2 `Person` nodes with the same `name` (either 'Barack' or 'Raback').

Assuming that the other `name` has only a single node, the `MATCH` clause will produce 2 rows -- which will cause the the `CREATE` clause to be executed twice.

To verify if this is your scenario, this query will show you how many nodes have each name:

```
MATCH (a:Person)
WHERE a.name IN ['Barack', 'Raback']
RETURN a.name, COUNT(a) as nodeCount
```

Comment: Note that for that query, the number of matches counted is influenced by the number of matches on the other, this won't provide good counts. Try this instead: `MATCH (a:Person) WHERE a.name in ['Barack', 'Raback'] RETURN a.name, count(a) as nodeCount`

Comment: For future travellers. Counting the nodes helped. The error turned out to be elsewhere: After creating nodes/relationships, they were retrieved (matched) by a different function in which I forgot to add direction to the arrow. I used `(a)-[r]-(b)` instead of `(a)-[r]->(b)`. Because of that, a single relationship would be returned twice (once for a-[r]-b and once for b-[r]-a).